# Is there any performance increase converting search term to lower case before LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Please have a look at the following 2 snippets:

```
var query = _ctx.Notes.Where(...);    
var searchLower = searchTerms.ToLower();
query = query.Where(a => a.Comment.ToLower().Contains(searchLower))
```

vs

```
var query = _ctx.Notes.Where(...);        
query = query.Where(a => a.Comment.ToLower().Contains(searchTerms.ToLower()))
```

Is there any peformance increase by converting the search terms before carrying out the LINQ query?

Comment: Note that according to "Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework" you should be converting `ToUpper()`, not `ToLower()`.  Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx

Comment: You should also have a look at Jon Skeet's answer to thus question around case sensitivity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234591/upper-vs-lower-case

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `Contains()`, use `IndexOf()` which takes a comparer:

```
var query = _ctx.Notes.Where(...);        
query = query.Where(a => a.Comment.IndexOf(searchTerms, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Comment: I think it should be `>= 0`

Comment: Is this actually quicker against an SQL database?

Comment: @jaffa: your best bet for speed against the database is to have a case-insensitive column with `Latin1_General_CS_AS` (or appropriate) and run that contains in a stored proc.